# Transfer pop up HTML content inside JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this working pop up HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<title>PopUp</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.popup.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery().popup();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#" id="triggerforpopup" rel="popup-open">Show popup</a>

<div id="popup-box">
This is the pop up content. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The actual pop up content is inside the:

```
<div id="popup-box">
</div>
```

Is it possible to transfer the pop up HTML content (..) to my JS file? Actually inside the jQuery function click event? Example:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {
    $('#triggerforpopup').live('click',(function() {
        //launch the pop code to HTML
    }));
});
```

So after the click event, the JS will simply pop it out, but it's originating inside the JS file not an HTML hidden on an existing content.

The reason is that I'm writing a Wordpress plugin and it would be convenient to have all this information in a JS file. I don't want putting additional HTML code in the existing template content which is hidden by default.

Thanks for helping.

**UPDATE:** I have created a fiddle for this one here: http://jsfiddle.net/codex_meridian/56ZpD/3/

```
(function (a) {
a.fn.popup = function (b) {
    var c, d = [self.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft, self.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop];
    a("body").append(c = a('<div id="popup-overlay"></div>')), _init = function () {
        _add_overlay(), _add_buttons(), a("#popup-box #popup-content").css("max-height", a(window).height() - 400), a(window).on("resize", function () {
            a("#popup-box #popup-content").css("max-height", a(window).height() - 400)
        })
    }, _add_overlay = function () {
        c.css({
            opacity: .85,
            position: "absolute",
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            width: "100%",
            "z-index": 99999,
            display: "none",
            height: a(document).height()
        })
    }, _show_overlay = function () {
        c.is(":visible") || c.fadeIn("fast")
    }, _hide_overlay = function () {
        c.is(":visible") && c.hide()
    }, _add_buttons = function () {
        a("a[rel=popup-close]").click(function () {
            return _hide_box(), !1
        }), a("a[rel=popup-open]").click(function () {
            return _show_box(), !1
        })
    }, _show_box = function () {
        if (!a("#popup-box").is(":visible")) {
            _show_overlay(), a("#popup-box").fadeIn("fast");
            var b = a("html");
            b.data("scroll-position", d), b.data("previous-overflow", b.css("overflow")), b.css("overflow", "hidden"), window.scrollTo(d[0], d[1])
        }
    }, _hide_box = function () {
        if (a("#popup-box").is(":visible")) {
            var b = a("html"),
                c = b.data("scroll-position");
            b.css("overflow", b.data("previous-overflow")), window.scrollTo(c[0], c[1]), _hide_overlay(), a("#popup-box").hide()
        }
    }, _init()
}
})(jQuery)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

`var popupHtml = $('<div>This is the pop up content. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</div>');`

> popupHtml.popup();

I found lots of issues in the popup plugin you have used. Fixed them to make it working. Have a look http://jsbin.com/oyamiy/6/watch

Comment: This one almost working but it gives me only the background of the pop up not the content itself.

Comment: Please share the URL of the site where you have take the popup library from.

Comment: Hi Raghavv,I've created the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/codex_meridian/56ZpD/3/

Comment: Your popup lib assumes a html to be present in dom with #popup-box. It needs to be modified. Can I modify the popup library code? If so, I would like non-minified version. If you can point to the source I can pick it from there.

Comment: Yes sure, you can do anything you want in the fiddle as long as the pop up would correctly display after clicking the link. Thanks.

Comment: I have updated my question, to include the non-minified version. Thanks.

Comment: @CodexMeridian: I have fixed the popup code to make it work. Also moved the code to jsbin as there was editing problem on jsfiddle. Please have a look. http://jsbin.com/oyamiy/6/watch

Answer (score 4):

You can write your content directly in your JS as a string and then use the innerHTML property of elements to set their value. You can do this in pure JS as follows.

```
var popup = document.getElementById("popup-box");
var html = "This is the pop up content. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
popup.innerHTML = html;
```

And you can do this in jQuery as follows:

```
$('#triggerforpopup').on('click', function() {
    $("#popup-box").html(html); // Where html is a variable containing your text.
});
```

Note: You can write in HTML tags and the like in your `html` string and they will be rendered as you would expect on the page. You are not limited to plaintext.

Note: `live` has been deprecated in jQuery as of jQuery 1.7. It has been replaced with `on`. See http://api.jquery.com/live/ and http://api.jquery.com/on/.

---

If you want to include everything in the JavaScript as mentioned in the comments, you can do this:

```
var popup = document.createElement("div");
popup.id = "popup-box";
popup.innerHTML = "your html here";
document.getElementById("parent element id").appendChild(popup);
```

What this does is create a new div element, set its id and then append it as the child element of the parent of your choice. You could just do a plain insert of the HTML string into another element, but by creating an element here you have a bit more flexibility regarding its placement.

Comment: would it be possible to have the <div id="popup-box"> to be included in the JS code..It is because in your example, you are assuming the popup-box div is outside JS. I need all pop-up HTML code to be inside the JS file. Thanks.

Comment: If you like to see an example of what I mean, I have created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/codex_meridian/56ZpD/3/